# Is payment gateway integration considered part of the deal?

Tags: difficult-client, price, clients, changes

Is a payment gateway, i.e, razor pay, part of the deal made on freelancer if I am a frontend developer and I made the deal with the client to just integrate APIs and make the UI in React?

Or should I ask for an increase in the price for integrating the payment gateway?

And isn't it something that the client should have told me before starting the project?

It's a fixed price project and it has a strict timeline. He didn't talk about this payment integration before. He just gave me the link to a website and asked me to build it and told me to pay a fixed amount which was of course negotiated by me.

And when we did the deal I clearly mentioned the pages and time I will make and he agreed to that. Now, after doing some work, I asked him what more is left and he repeated the list along with the payment integration. Which I reminded him was not there in the deal. To which he said, of course, it's by default there on a shopping website.

Comment: Why have you tagged the question [tag:difficult-client]? Is the client difficult indeed? Did you have any written agreement on the project? What's in it? Is the project for fixed price or does it have some kind of scope-based basis (time-and-materials)? Please clarify, because your question may have different answers depending on these aspects.

Comment: Yes, it's a fixed price project and it has a strict timeline. He didn't talk about this payment integration before. He just gave me the link to a website and asked me to build it and told me to pay a fixed amount which was of course negotiated by me. And when we did the deal I clearly mentioned the pages and time I will make and he agreed to that. Now, after doing some work, I asked him what more is left and he repeated the list along with Payment integration. Which I reminded him was not there in the deal. To which he said, of course, it's by default there on a shopping website.

Comment: And yes, the website I am making is kind of a shopping website.

Comment: @Blatzo Please update your question with the new information from your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> He didn't talk about this payment integration before.

Then it's not your problem. It's his problem 1000%.  You just politely say that it wasn't specified. And if you feel it's outside of your capabilities say that too. It's then his job to go find someone to do that for him. He still owes you for the portion of his project you agreed to do and complete.

Now as a consultant who doesn't use freelancer, I would either suggest to the client some trusted backend developer I know or if I'm capable just give him an price & time estimate for the new work.

Comment: I did the same thing, I politely told him that it was not ever mentioned to me before while making the deal. And that, he should asked about it while making the deal because only then I would have told him if it's possible for me or not to add it in the given timeframe and price. For now, I simply told him I won't be able to do it.

Answer (score 3):

This should be defined and negotiated **before** any work begins and detailed in any contract.

The purpose of a contract is to *clearly* define what is to be completed and what fees are associated with that --- you agree to do X, Y and Z, the client agrees to pay XX.

Whether or not something is "part of the deal" should be determined prior to work starting. If additional work has been presented after price and scope negotiations have concluded, then yes, it is additional work and additional compensation should be negotiated.

Answer (score 3):

There is not an objective answer to whether it's part of the deal, as you and the client obviously disagree.

Most would agree that ideally **all** requirements should be spelled out in a contract - and that is best practice and tends to be the best way to avoid this type of situation. However, both parties also often have implicit expectations - many of which we don't need to explicitly spell out in a contract.

There is no nice way to resolve the issue; it will either involve re-negotiation or you biting the bullet. Only you know where you are on that spectrum, as it depends on your financial situation, the amount of other work you have and what the long term prospects with the client are.